# IE 8 install on Win Server 2003 (Xeon): iesetup.exe is valid but for other machine type

Tags: internet-explorer-8, installation

I was trying to install IE 8 on a Win Server 2003 SP2 on a Xeon machine.

I went to Microsoft download site and got this file (for Windows Server 2003 64-bit)

IE8-WindowsServer2003-x64-ENU.exe

But during installation I got an error of "The image file update\iesetup.exe is valid, but is for a machine type other than the current machine"

For completeness, I then tried download the other file (for Windows Server 2003 32-bit)

IE8-WindowsServer2003-x86-ENU.exe

And this one gave me an error message of "... is not a valid Win32 application"

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Install this version from the link above. it should solve the issue.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20335

Also check your os base. You can type this command at the command line:
systeminfo